# Is there a connection between the fire of Gehenna and the fire that is kindled by an unruly (ungodly) tongue?

Tags: titus, hell, tongue

In James chapter 3, counsel is given about controlling one’s tongue (the words one speaks) so as not to set aflame “the course of nature and being inflamed by Gehenna” (James 3:6, as in the literal English under the Greek, in the A.V. Interlinear.)

> “And the tongue is a fire, a world of iniquity: so is the tongue among
> our members, that it defileth the whole body, and setteth on fire the
> course of nature; and it is set on fire of hell” James 3:6 A.V.

***Does not the literal English translation under the Greek in the Interlinear version make more sense than the quote above?***  **What could being “set on fire of hell” (or “Gehenna”) mean?**

Τροχια is 'path' and τροχος is 'course' (KJV). τὸν τροχὸν τῆς γενέσεως apparently means the order of existence. So, **how is this path, or course, set by an unruly tongue, connected to being inflamed by Gehenna?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the AV interlinear translation - compare the BLB of James 3:6 -

> The tongue also is a fire, the world of unrighteousness. The tongue is
> set among our members, defiling all the body, and setting on fire the
> course of nature, and *itself* being set on fire by Gehenna.

Note that James is discussing three different outcomes of an unruly tongue (see appendix below)

- *defiles the body* (how many people have suffered personal health problems because of an unruly disposition evidenced by a caustic tongue?!)
- *sets on fire the course of nature* (ie, makes the social atmosphere around people very hot and unpleasant, and thus, alienates what might otherwise be good friends)
- itself is set on fire in gehenna (the final destination of all the wicked and their sin)

Thus, James sets out the advantages of taming the tongue/words as encompassing all three things - one's personal body & health, one's personal life and social affairs, and one's ultimate destiny.

Benson summarizes this well when he observes (Quoting Macknight):

> "The wonderful mechanism of the human body, and its power of affecting
> and of being affected by the soul, is in this passage aptly
> represented by the wheels of a machine which act on each other. The
> pernicious influence of the tongue, in first spotting, and then
> destroying, both the bodies and the souls of men, arises from the
> language which it frames, whereby it inflames men’s passions to such a
> degree, that, being no longer under the direction of their reason,
> those passions push them on to such actions as are destructive both of
> their bodies and souls.” Some writers, by the natural wheel, or course
> of nature, understand the successive generations of men, one
> generation going, and another coming, without intermission; according
> to which interpretation the apostle’s meaning is, that the tongue hath
> set on fire our forefathers, it inflameth us, and will have the same
> influence on those who come after us. And it is set on fire of hell —
> Put here for the devil; as, by a like metonymy, heaven is put for God.
> Satan influences the heart, and its wickedness overflows by the
> tongue, and tends, by its fatal consequences, to produce a very hell
> upon earth. “The use we ought to make of the doctrine taught in this
> highly figurative passage is obvious. Being surrounded with such a
> mass of combustible matter, we should take great care not to send from
> our tongues the least spark by which it may be kindled, lest we
> ourselves, with those whom we set on fire, be consumed in the flames
> which we raise.” — Macknight.

**APPENDIX - Ellicott comments in James 3:6**

> Three temptations “to smite with the tongue” are specially powerful of
> evil: viz., as a relief from passion, as a gratification of spite, as
> revenge for wrong. The first is experienced by hot tempered folk; the
> second yielded to by the malicious; the third welcomed by the
> otherwise weak and defenceless; and all of us at times are in each of
> these divisions. Then, again, there are the “foolish talkings”
> (Ephesians 5:4), and worse, the jestings at holy things, and
> misquotations of Scripture: all to be avoided as not becoming saints.
> If then we would “walk in love” we must curb the tongue; but, better
> still, strive to cleanse the heart, and so be quite determined that
> nothing shall go forth but words of meekness and affection.