# How is the tongue set on fire by hell?

Tags: james

James 3:6 NASB

> “And the tongue is a fire, the very world of iniquity; the tongue is set among our members as that which defiles the entire body, and sets on fire the course of our life, and is set on fire by hell.”

‭‭What does it mean for the tongue to be “set on fire by hell”, and how does this relate to the rest of the verse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a connection between the fire of Gehenna and the fire that is kindled by an unruly (ungodly) tongue?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/85163/is-there-a-connection-between-the-fire-of-gehenna-and-the-fire-that-is-kindled-b)

Answer (score 1):

James 3:6 is the further exploration of James 3:5;

> 5 Likewise, the tongue is a small part of the body, but it makes great boasts. **Consider what a great forest is set on fire by a small spark**. (James 3:5 NIV)

Therefore a small spark that set on fire to a forest is a metaphor that a small tongue could ignite conflict that lead to a big calamity. In James' interpretation, it was Satan who worked in behind and therefore he described it as "set on fire by hell (Satan)".

He further described, **'no human being can tame the tongue'** (James 3:8 NIV),  that in his mind, the tongue is either under influence of Satan, or receiving the grace from God (James 3:13-18). Though everyone has a tongue, but not everyone's tongue will set a fire, as he said

> 10 Out of the same mouth come praise and cursing. My brothers and sisters, **this should not be**.
>
> 11 **Can both fresh water and salt water flow from the same spring**? (James 3:10-11 NIV)

Those who can keep his tongue in good use received wisdom from God, as he said

> 17 But the wisdom that comes from heaven is first of all pure; then peace-loving, considerate, submissive, full of mercy and good fruit, impartial and sincere. (James 3:17 NIV)